# sqlite choose wrong query plan

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization, query-planner

Consider following example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, b) WITHOUT ROWID;
WITH RECURSIVE
    cnt(x) AS (VALUES(1000) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt WHERE x<2000)
INSERT INTO t1(a,b) SELECT x, x FROM cnt;
CREATE INDEX t1b ON t1(b);
```

This query creates table without rowid column and insert values(x, x) where 
1000 < x < 2000. In order to help query planner lets run ANALYZE.

```
ANALYZE;

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE b BETWEEN 500 AND 2500;

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE b BETWEEN 2900 AND 3000;
```

The output in both cases is:`0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING COVERING INDEX t1b (b>? AND b<?)`
However, there is no sense to use index (for the first query) for the reason that anyway we have to iterate through whole table, so ordinary SCAN TABLE seems to be more efficient. Exactly in this way tables with rowid work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a, b);
WITH RECURSIVE
   cnt(x) AS (VALUES(1000) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt WHERE x<2000)
INSERT INTO t1(a,b) SELECT x, x FROM cnt;
CREATE INDEX t1a ON t1(a);
ANALYZE;

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE a BETWEEN 500 AND 2500;

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE a BETWEEN 2900 AND 3000;
```

In this case output will be:`0|0|0|SCAN TABLE t1`
 and `0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING INDEX t1a (a>? AND a<?)`

So, could anybody explain how query planner optimize queries for WITHOUT ROWID tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The output in both cases is:
> 0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING COVERING INDEX t1b (b>? AND b<?)
>
> However, there is no sense to use index (for
> the first query) for the reason that anyway we have to iterate through
> whole table, so ordinary SCAN TABLE seems to be more efficient.

You missed the **COVERING INDEX** part: that means it is using the index-only — not accessing the table at all.

You are right that a regular index access (without "COVERING") might be slower than a full table scan if all rows are needed, but this is not the case for an index-only scan.

Read more about index-only scans here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index

**EDIT**

WITHOUT ROWID are in SQLite what are so-called *clustered indexes* in other databases: they contain **all** table columns. Therefore, there is no need to visit the table, even if you select all columns (like in `select *`).

Read more about clustered indexes here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index

Comment: So there is no sense to run analyze in order to optimize queries on tables without rowid?

Comment: @NikitaRock It might make: the database might still chose to use another index additionally to the clustered index.

Comment: But anyway, if add third column in table, then index on t1b will not be COVERING anymore(in WITHOUT ROWID case). However, query planner still prefers search using index, rather than full scan table.

Comment: Moreover, I really didn't get this: "there is no need to visit the table". As far as I know, in SQLite table is held as b-tree index for rowid or primary key and there is no heap table.

Comment: No matter how many columns, a clustered index (WITHOUT ROWID) has all of them. As you said: if the table is WITHOUT ROWID, there is no other, artificial structure to visit (in case of SQLite, the "heap" is actually a b-tree as well).